# Win7 activation

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation, events

Yesterday the computer asked me to I activate it, because "more hardware changed"...

No one of them changed really, the last hw changing was in the last year in this notebook.

What I did? I don't know.
I used Virtual PC, I used VirtualBox, and VMWare Player only.

I actually saw a video in KMPLAYER when I got this Windows message.

Somebody said me that HW failure, and persistent HW error can produce this error.
When I firstly installed MS Antivirus, it said that my Windows7 is not legal - what is not true, this is OEM Windows...
But VMWARE is also suspicious...

Do you know where I can find what problem can caused this Activation?
What HW changed? Can I see this from the logs?

Thanks for the help!

Regards:
  dd

Comment: Please check the link for more update  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/how-exactly-does-windows-7-retail-vs-oem/fae7b2ab-c530-45e6-aeb3-cc55cf7b9231

Comment: It is giving you these errors inside of virtual machines, or your actual computer?

Comment: The activation message apperared in the REAL machine. The virtual machines are using Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you re-run windows activation successfully? I know it's treating the symptom, but that's normally all one can hope for with Windows anyway.

Comment: I can reactivate it, but I want to know what caused this. 
Maybe virtual machines? Or real hw defect? I want to know this to do something...